# Npm command not recognized (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

After installing java 8 openjdk and exporting the variable via export I ran the following command:

```
source /etc/enviorment
```

I after that when I try to run npm run tests-e2e, it says the command is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `source /etc/environment` has reset your shell's environment variables back to their default values, throwing away any customisations that were applied by your shell's startup scripts (/etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile and so on).  In particular, it looks like you've lost the customised value of `$PATH` that carried the path to the directory where the `npm` command lives.

To recover, you can do any of:

- execute `exec bash -l` to get a new shell that will execute the
  startup scripts and therefore rebuild a properly customised `$PATH` variable
- if you're using the GUI, close the terminal window and open a new one
- log out and then log back in